# Canvas selectable over div

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have a HTML5 canvas on which I perform some actions and catch some events. On the canvas(over) I have 4 divs. Is it possible to see the div's and the content of the divs but make them act invisible. For example when I go with my mouse over the div I actually go over the canvas?

I hope you can help me!

`Simple example:` http://jsfiddle.net/ygjen/5/

get mouse cordinates also on going over the divs

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Comment: Everything getts dynamically built!

Comment: @Jacob when somebody asks for code here, it doesn't mean the exact code of your application but a minimal code demonstrating your problem. And it's better when it comes with a fiddle (for example at http://jsbin.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events)

```
 pointer-events: none;
```

Supported in everything besides IE8 and below.. but Canvas isn't supported in IE8 or below anyway so that point is moot.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ygjen/6/)**